# accessing/sharing an object from another thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, javafx

I have a Java solution in which its main thread runs a JavaFX desktop application. In addition, another thread is created that takes care of a REST service by using an embedded web-server. By using a REST client, I can access the REST service, but I cannot access an object existing in the context of the main thread because I am not actually in that thread. Please any suggestions on how to approach this problem.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static MyBrowser myBrowser;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

        myBrowser = new MyBrowser("http://localhost:8080/terminal");

        Scene scene1 = null;

        Screen s1 = null;       
        Rectangle2D screenBounds = Screen.getScreens().get(0).getVisualBounds();

        s1 = Screen.getScreens().get(0); // i replaced per 0
        scene1 = new Scene(myBrowser, screenBounds.getWidth(), screenBounds.getHeight());


        primaryStage.setTitle("Terminal 1");
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.setX(s1.getVisualBounds().getMinX());
        primaryStage.setY(s1.getVisualBounds().getMinY());
        primaryStage.setWidth(s1.getVisualBounds().getWidth());
        primaryStage.setHeight(s1.getVisualBounds().getHeight());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        log.info("before show() method...");
        primaryStage.show();

        // launch jetty web-server for REST services
        log.info("about to create a Thread object for running start() method...");

        MyThread jettyThread = new MyThread();
        jettyThread.setDaemon(true);
        jettyThread.start();

    }


    public static MyBrowser getMyBrowser() {
        return myBrowser;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }



        public class MyBrowser extends Region {

            HBox toolbar;
            public WebView webView = new WebView();
            WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
            ...                 
    }

    public class MyThread extends Thread {

        public void run() {

            try {

                EmbeddedWebServerController.start();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide example code. Also, if i understood you correctly, the _synchronized_ keyword is the way to go

Comment: Hi user2358582, here you will see the code. Pls detail how you would implement the synchronized keyword. Thanks

Comment: I dont know if its the perfect way to go, but change the method Main.getMyBrowser to "public static synchronized MyBrowser getMyBrowser()" and get the object like: Main.getMyBrowser() in the method mythread.run

Comment: The only way threads can share information is by updating objects to which they all have access.  The simplest way, but kind of ugly, is for the threads to communicate through some `static` variable or some _singleton_ object.  A more sophisticated way is for the code that creates the threads to create the shared object first, and then pass it to each of the new threads as a constructor argument.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion but it did not work. It throws the following exception: _javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = qtp692220116-27 - /billValidator/rest/entry-point/deposit_

Comment: **Hi James**, in line with your first comment on using _static_ I did it for the object myBrowser, but though I can access it, it also throws the exception shown in the previous comment. Any explanations for it ?

Comment: Be careful of some of the answers and comments posted for this question.  JavaFX application programming requires that: a) Commands which might access or manipulate the scene graph *must* be executed on the JavaFX thread, otherwise the application may break in an undetermined way or throw a "Not on FX application thread" exception AND b) Commands running on the JavaFX application thread not be long running tasks, otherwise the application UI will become unresponsive while the JavaFX application thread is consumed.

Comment: Solutions such as use of the keywords synchronized or volatile are not appropriate.  You need to investigate: [Concurrency in JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm), [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) and the [JavaFX application lifecycle and threading advice](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a static reference to your object, the other thread will be able to reach it. To make sure you see the correct value, you have to make the field `volatile`:

```
public volatile static MyBrowser myBrowser;
```

In general you have to set fields to be volatile when sharing between threads, unless they are final. The other way to do it would be to add the `synchronized` keyword to the getters and setters for `myBrowser`. Using `synchronized` would also ensure that the thread has the intrinsic lock so that you can do other actions atomically (such as if you need to do some work before you assign the field a new value).

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestions